# Time Scales in the BBGKY Hierarchy

Tags: statistical-mechanics, dimensional-analysis, estimation, kinetic-theory

(I am following Chapter 3 of Mehran Kardar's Statistical Mechanics of Particles)When working with the BBGKY hierarchy of equations, we get the following for the two-particle probability density $f_2$:
$$
 \newcommand{\p}[2]{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}} \newcommand{\f}[2]{\frac{ #1}{ #2}} \newcommand{\l}[0]{\left(} \newcommand{\r}[0]{\right)} \newcommand{\mean}[1]{\langle #1 \rangle}\newcommand{\e}[0]{\varepsilon} \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left|#1\right>} \newcommand{\bra}[1]{\left<#1\right|} \newcommand{\braoket}[3]{\left<#1\right|#2\left|#3\right>}
\l \p{}{t}+\f{\vec{p}_1}{m}\cdot \p{}{\vec{q}_1}+\f{\vec{p}_2}{m}\cdot \p{}{\vec{q}_2}-\p{U(|\vec{q}_1-\vec{q}_2|)}{\vec{q}_1}\cdot \l \p{}{\vec{p}_1}-\p{}{\vec{p}_2}\r\r f_2$$
$$=\int dV_3\l \p{U(|\vec q_1-\vec q_3|)}{\vec q_1}\cdot \p{}{\vec p_1}+\p{U(|\vec{q}_2-\vec{q}_3|)}{\vec{q}_2}\cdot \p{}{\vec p_2}\r f_3$$

where the notation is as follows (I am following Chapter 3 of Mehran Kardar's Statistical Mechanics of Particles):

- $\vec q_i$ is the position of the $i$th particle.
- $\vec p_i$ is the momentum of the $i$th particle.
- $U(|\vec q_i-\vec q_j|)$ is the interaction potential between the $i$th and the $j$th particles.
- $f_n(\vec q_1,...,\vec q_n,\vec p_1,...,\vec p_n)$ (argument dropped in above) is the n-particle distribution function (i.e. the probability that you would find any arbitrary $n$ particles with position $\vec q_1,...,\vec q_n$ and momenta $\vec p_1,...,\vec p_n$).
- $dV_3$ is a phase space volume, $dV_3=d\vec q_3 d\vec p_3$.

In order to truncate the hierarchy, we estimate relevant time-scales as follows:
$$
\frac{1}{\tau_U} \approx \frac{\partial U}{\partial{\vec{q}}} . \frac{\partial }{\partial{q}} \approx \frac{L}{v}  \\
\frac{1}{\tau_c} \approx \frac{\partial \mathcal{V}}{\partial{\vec{q}}} . \frac{\partial }{\partial{q}} \approx \frac{d}{v} 
$$

where $d, L$ are the distances over which $\mathcal{V}, U$ respectively vary , and $v$ is the typical velocity ($\approx 10^2 m/s$) of the particles. After similar estimations on the RHS, we drop it because the collision terms are much smaller than the LHS.

**Question**

How should I systematically think about this derivation of time scales on the LHS? The text argues that the relevant time-scales there will be related to the time the particle takes to cross the "length-scales" of the potential. Here, the length-scales refer to $d, L$  for $\mathcal{V}, U$ respectively. I am unable to massage the expressions for the $\tau$s into a form that justifies this quantitatively.

Any explanation of the same will be immensely helpful.

(related, but not equivalent question: [Reason for ignoring the collisional integral in the BBGKY hierarchy $f_2$?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/346823/reason-for-ignoring-the-collisional-integral-in-the-bbgky-hierarchy-f-2))